# How to return different child classes using Mockito

Tags: mockito

How can Mockito return different child classes.
Consider the following.

```
when(response.readEntity(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(baseModel);
```

I want to return different classes that extend baseModel.

Thanks,

Comment: `thenReturn` won't accept a subclass?!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the alternate syntax recommended, but for other reasons:

```
doReturn(baseModel)
    .when(response).readEntity(any(Class.class));
```

Its *caveat* (which ironically helps you) is that it doesn't enforce return types.

Answer (score 0):

```
when(response.readEntity(any(Class.class))).thenReturn(baseModel);
```

You're telling Mockito that you're passing `readEntity` any *class object*, and `readEntity`'s generic expects you to return *an object of type Class* (including a subclass of Class, if that could exist).

If you're looking to return any object, you should instead have:

```
when(response.readEntity(any(Object.class))).thenReturn(baseModel);
```

or...

```
when(response.readEntity(anyObject())).thenReturn(baseModel);
```